# PostGIS: Converting Text WKT/WKB/WKB Hex to Polygon

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, postgis, geopandas, geoalchemy2

I am importing Polygon shapes into a PostGIS database, using Python (GeoPandas, SQLAlchemy, GeoAlchemy2). I followed the instructions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361336/write-geodataframe-into-sql-database/43375829).

I have a database with a table named `maps_region` with a column/field called `geom`.

I am able to get the Polygon field (named `geom`) to import into the PostGIS database table in text format (WKT, WKB, and WKB Hex), but, I am unable to successfully convert this text column into a proper Polygon format in the database.

I tried importing with the `geom` field in several different formats-- in Well-Known Text (WKT) format, WKB format, and WKB Hex format-- but could not convert to Polygon from any of the three formats.

For instance, I imported the shapes into the `geom` field as WKT format, and then converted to WKB Hex format, using the following command, which worked fine:

```
database=> UPDATE maps_region SET geom = ST_GeomFromText(geom, 4326);
UPDATE 28
```

However, when I then try to convert the `geom` field from a `text` format into a `Polygon` type, I get the following errors:

```
database=> ALTER TABLE maps_region ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE Geometry(POLYGON, 4326);
ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiPolygon) does not match column type (Polygon)
database=> ALTER TABLE maps_region ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE Geometry(MULTIPOLYGON, 4326);
ERROR:  Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
```

I tried both ways: converting to Polygon, and converting to MultiPolygon-- and neither worked. Instead, the error messages were just reversed!

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I realized that the shapes were being registered in mixed format: all but one were in `Polygon` format, while one was in `MultiPolygon` format -- [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOzcy.png). Looks like this sufficiently explains the issue/invalid conversion.